# Problems restoring using Backup Exec 10D on Exchange 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, backupexec

Backup Exec 10D, Win2K3 SBS, Exchange 2003.
I'm trying to do a restore job from a tape on exchange which only houses 1 mailbox store.

I've created the Recovery Storage Group and linked it to the original Mailbox Store, made sure that it was dismounted and then tried the recovery job.
It spits the error:

```
Job ended: Friday, 12 November 2010 at 3:10:29 PM
Completed status: Failed
Final error: 0xe000ff00 - Unable to restore some Microsoft Exchange components because one or more of the databases are currently mounted.  Use the Exchange System Manager to dismount the databases, and then retry the job.
Final error category: Resource Errors

For additional information regarding this error refer to link V-79-57344-65280
```

I haven't tried to dismount the main Mailbox Store as there are still users on the system.
I tried a registry key hack to ignore the state of the mailbox stores but ended up with this error:

```
Job ended: Friday, 12 November 2010 at 3:29:40 PM
Completed status: Failed
Final error: 0xe000fe30 - A communications failure has occurred.
Final error category: Server Errors

For additional information regarding this error refer to link V-79-57344-65072
```

I am wondering whether I will need to dismount the main store and whether there is a possibility that current data will be overwritten with old.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is a day late and a dollar short, but... what version of Exchange 2003 are you running? Standard or Enterprise?

Standard only allows you to have a single Storage Group, while Enterprise allows for 4.

I suspect Veritas/Symantec means for everyone using 10d to do a brick-level backup of Exchange and can, therefore, restore individual mailboxes.

A couple years ago I could have told you why you're allowed to create that 2nd Storage Group with the Standard version, but I've forgotten the answer.

I think what I ended up doing was:

- Installing Exchange on a completely separate box (you can re-direct the backup to it)
- Restoring the Storage Group to the newly-created server
- Exporting the mail I needed to a PST
- Using ExMerge to get the data in the necessary mailbox
- Destroying the newly-created Exchange server

Soon after all this, I handed in my two week notice...

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the BackupExec Administrators Guide? If not, that's where I would start. There's an entire section regarding backing up and restoring Exchange. Also, a quick Google search returned this:

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH29719

Hope it helps.